# How many http clients is needed per application?

Tags: http, go

What is the best practice for managing http clients in Go application assuming that app makes a lot of requests to different services? There are few options over the internet:

- Use one client for whole application
- Use one client per external service
- Use one client per request

I guess second solution is the most valid one since it allows to reuse TCP connection because each service has a separate connection pool. Any thoughts? Especially regarding first solution - what problems it may lead to? Or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general answer to this. It depends on what you're doing. Scope your http clients to their use cases. If the entire application needs a single instance, use one. If you need different ones for different parts of your application, or even for each request, do that.

If you need different timeouts, different cookie jars, different proxy configuration, different TLS certificates, or *any other different configuration*, you'll need more than one.

If you need the same configuration for your entire application, then it's reasonable to use a single client instance.

If you have *shared* state between different parts of your application (such as a cookie jar) then you *must* use the same client<sup>*</sup> across your application.

---

<sup>*</sup>Or find some other way to synchronize the shared state, but using a shared client is probably easiest.